# jenkins docker slave inbound connection with self signed certificate

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We move our Jenkins to use a self-signed certificate and then docker slaves (inbound, image: jenkins-inbound-agent) strat to fail to connect as the certificate is not trusted.
We try to add -cert `@<path to file>` and we get an error `empty input` (we check the file and it is OK)
Second, we tried to add the certificate as env but then it complained about an unknown option `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

What can be done?